# has anyone seen this error installing ape?[fixed]

Tags: framework, ape

I have ethash installed from C:\block\ethash
and i ran pip install eth-ape in C:\block
when i got this at the end

> Building wheels for collected packages: pyethash   Building wheel for
> pyethash (pyproject.toml) ... error   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Building wheel for pyethash (pyproject.toml) did not run
> successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [8 lines of output]
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
> internal.c
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
> io.c
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
> io_win32.c
> c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c': No such file or directory
> error: command 'D:\vs\New folder\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit code 2
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyethash Failed
> to build pyethash ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyethash, which is
> required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

installed it in linux